# Нужно создать службу занятости

Tags: c#

Лабораторная по C#. Нужно создать службу занятости используя классы и методы. В моей голове задача выглядит так:

1. Пользователь вводит свои данные (имя, статус(есть у него работа или нет), наличие образования(есть высшее или нет) и специальность(при наличии образования))
2. В зависимости от ответов ему должно предложить разные вакансии. Если у человека нет образования, то ему должны предложить вакансии, где оно не нужно
3. Если у пользователя есть работа, мы вежливо попросим его не тратить наше время
4. Ещё можно было бы если человек безработный предложить ему выбор: хочет он найти работу или получать пособие по безработице

У меня есть некоторый код, но я вообще дальше без понятия что делать, времени у меня до четверга.

```
Person applicant = new("Неизвестно", "Неизвестен", "Неизвестно", "Неизвестна");
Console.WriteLine("Введите своё имя");
applicant.name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Вы безработный?");
applicant.status = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("У вас есть образование?");
applicant.haveEducation = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Какое у вас образование?(если нет образования поставьте прочерк)");
applicant.specialization = Console.ReadLine();
applicant.Print();

class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string status;
    public string haveEducation;
    public string specialization;

    public Person(string name, string status, string haveEducation, string specialization)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.haveEducation = haveEducation;
        this.specialization = specialization;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {name}, Статус: {status}, Наличие образования: {haveEducation}, Специализация: {specialization}");
    }
}
```

Чуть дополнил и сейчас выглядит так, но я всё ещё не знаю как сделать так, чтобы в ответ на введённые пользователем данные программа выводила вакансии

```
class Vacancy
{
    public string softwareEngineering = "Системный аналитик, Системный архитектор, Проектировщик программных систем, Конструктор программного обеспечения, Программист, Специалист по тестированию программного обеспечения";
    public string graphicDesigner = "Графический дизайнер, UX-дизанер, Рекламный арт-директор, Иллюстратор, Моушн-дизайнер";
    public string architect = "BIM-менеджер-проектировщик, Архитектор ландшафтов, Архитектор энергетически автономных домов, Архитектор-градостроитель, Архитектор-реставратор";
    public string economist = "Экономист-аналитик, Бухгалтер, Аудитор, Финансовый директор, Специалист по документообороту, Руководитель планово-экономического отдела";
    public string lawyer = "Секретарь судебных заседаний, Помощник судьи, Прокурор, Судья, Нотариус";
    public string uneducated = "Уборщик, Официант, Курьер, Таксист, Грузчик, Продавец, Мусорщик, Водитель автобуса, Охранник";

    public void Print2(string vacancy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вам доступны следующие вакансии:");
        Console.WriteLine(vacancy);
    }
}
```

Comment: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу_

Comment: haveEducation - это `bool`, а не `string`

Comment: ну так я итак пытался решить её и привел код. В чем проблема?

Comment: У вас есть класс персоны, теперь нужен класс вакансии с требованиями. Далее в цикле опросив пользователя смотрите все вакансии и выводите на экран те, которые совпали по критериям.

Comment: ПО сути тебе надо прописать несколько if'ов........как бы и всё....если  совсем просто

Comment: да, но преподаватель дал чёткое задание использовать классы и методы

Comment: создай класс организации, сделай метод, на вход в метод подай персону, а дальше в этом методе if'ы

Comment: @aepot, я не знаю как их связать и я даже не знаю как по-нормальному осуществить ввод информации пользователем

Comment: Чем ваш ввод ненормальный? Механизм создания вакансии от персоны ничем не отличается, ее даже не вводить с клавы, а захардкодить несколько штук и создать из них любую коллекцию. Из них и выбирать.

Comment: @aepot, понял, буду пробовать. Спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: у меня ещё вопрос. А как  тогда используя методы и классы обработать ввод пользователя?

Comment: если у тебя консольное приложение, то никто не мешает тебе использовать для ввода пользовательских данных `Console.ReadLine()`; по-другому просто невозможно, если только в коде не прописывать конкретные значения, но я думаю это не то что тебе нужно

Comment: потом на основе этих данных создаешь пользователя и предлагаешь ему вакансии

Comment: @Pekor, я чуть дополнил код. Не могли бы вы взглянуть и помочь мне?

Comment: Код неправильный, учите ООП. Класс-объект, это надо понять прежде чем приступить к выполнению задания. Подсказка: класс вакансии не должен содержать констант с текстом, там должно быть поле для названия, чтрока и критерии ее требований к образованию и т.д. А когда вы создаете вакансию через new, вот там и передавайте в класс название и другие критерии, точно так же как с Person, вы же этот класс сами написали, верно? Что мешает вам по образу и подобию создать вакансии?

Comment: @aepot, то есть вакансии я должен создавать как объекты класса Vacancy? Звучит логично. Затупил я что-то, учитывая что сам до этого более менее нормально создал класс Person и объект к нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал `haveEducation` `char` просто чтобы было проще

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public char haveEducation;
    public Person(string name, char haveEducation)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.haveEducation = haveEducation;
    }
}

class Vacancy {
  public string name;
  public char needEducation
}

class Program {

  public void Main(){
  
  List<Vacancy> vacs = new List<Vacancy>();

  ... //тут сам заполнишь vacs что-то типо vacs[0] = new Vacancy...

  Console.WriteLine("Введите своё имя");
  var name = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("У вас есть образование? y or n");
  var haveEducation = (char)Console.ReadLine();
  Person person = new(name , haveEducation);

  Console.WriteLine("Вот вакансии для тебя:");
  foreach(var vac in vacs){
    if(vac.needEducation == person.haveEducation)
      Console.WriteLine(vac.name);

}
}
}
```

остальные поля + проверку на безработицу + функции `print` + конструкторы думаю сам доделаешь, это все довольно просто если понимать смысл классов и объектов, а также как с ними работать в `Main`